# Web Config Redirects

Tags: c#, url-rewriting, web-config

I have links from my site, let's call them the following: `www.mysite.com.au/fly-cruise and www.mysite.com.au/fly-cruise/some-deal`.

I would like both of these types of URLs to return to my new page:
`www.mysite.com.au/Packages/FlyCruise`.

I am able to get the first one working using the following in my Web config file:

```
<rewrite>
  <rewriteMaps>
    <rewriteMap name="flycruise">
      <add key="/fly-cruise" value="/Packages/FlyCruise/" />
    </rewriteMap>
  </rewriteMaps>
  <rules>
    <rule name="Redirect rule1 for flycruise">
      <match url=".*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{flycruise:{REQUEST_URI}}" pattern="(.+)" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="{C:1}" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

But I'm not sure how to also specify anything after `fly-cruise/`.

Do I need a separate rule to do this? Also, what would the proper term be for referring to that trailing part of the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to redirect all urls which starts with `/fly-cruise` and anything after. Example:

`/fly-cruise`,  `/fly-cruise/abc`, `/fly-cruise/bcd` etc

You can use single rule for that:

```
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect rule for flycruise">
            <match url="^fly-cruise" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="/Packages/FlyCruise" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Absolute legend! This is exactly what I was looking for thank you!

Comment: If I wanted to retain what was trailing /fly-cruise how would I do that? For example if I wanted fly-cruise/this-deal to redirect to /Packages/FlyCruise/this-deal?

Comment: @BigD It should be like this `<rule name="Redirect rule for flycruise">
            <match url="^fly-cruise(.*)" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="/Packages/FlyCruise{R:1}" />
        </rule>`